# Optimization when looping through two vectors of different lengths

Tags: c++, performance, compilation, compiler-optimization

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct timeval timeStart,
                    timeEnd;
```

Create vectors of random 0 and 1. We will benchmark the time to sum them up.

```
    int n1 = 450000000;  // size of vector v1
    int n2 = 500000000;  // size of vector v2
    int i;
    vector<bool> v1(n1);
    vector<bool> v2(n2);

    for (i=0; i < n1 ; i++)
    {
    v1[i] = rand() % 2;
    }
    for (i=0; i < n2 ; i++)
    {
    v2[i] = rand() % 2;
    }
```

First technique to sum. Sum these vectors with two complete (independent) loops

```
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);
    for (i=0; i < n1 ; i++)
    {
      sum1 += v1[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i < n2 ; i++)
    {
      sum2 += v2[i];
    }
    gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);
    cout << "Two complete loops took " << ((timeEnd.tv_sec - timeStart.tv_sec) * 1000000 + timeEnd.tv_usec - timeStart.tv_usec) << " us"  << endl;
```

Second technique. Sum these vectors with a complete loop and a partial loop

```
    sum1 = 0;
    sum2 = 0;
    gettimeofday(&timeStart, NULL);
    for (i=0; i < n1 ; i++)
    {
      sum1 += v1[i];
      sum2 += v2[i];
    }
    for (i=n1; i < n2 ; i++)
    {
      sum2 += v2[i];
    }
    gettimeofday(&timeEnd, NULL);
    cout << "With a reduced second loop, it took " << ((timeEnd.tv_sec - timeStart.tv_sec) * 1000000 + timeEnd.tv_usec - timeStart.tv_usec) << " us"  << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I systematically get an output of the kind

```
Two complete loops took 13291126 us
With a reduced second loop, it took 12758827 us
```

I would have expected either the same time (if the compiler optimized the first solution as I excepted it to) or I expected the complete two loops to take considerably more time (and not just 5%-10% longer) than the partial second loop.

What is the compiler most likely doing here? Should I consider using partial loops in the future when looping through two vectors of different lengths?

---

FYI, I compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp`, with version

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Consider swapping the order of the two, and see what you get.

Comment: Also, one `int i;` is probably not an optimization (or whatever you thought).

Comment: @LogicStuff I would have thought (wrongly apparently) that allocating memory for an `int` only once rather than 4 times would be strategic indeed. Isn't it? Is it because when initialized more often the computer ensured the memory slot for `1` is closer to the vector it loops over or something like that?  I don't fully understand what swapping you are referring to. I naively tried to swap the order of what technic is being used first but the 'two complete loops' remained the slowest of the two.

Comment: You didn't compile with optimizations, so your results are meaningless.

Comment: The loop just don't have *that* much overhead: for one, the branch prediction works perfectly and, perhaps, the loops are quite small as to be "optimised" by the Intel's Loop Stream Detector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try to explain the similarities in the execution times:

When you do this:

```
for (i=0; i < n1 ; i++)
{
  sum1 += v1[i];
}
for (i=0; i < n2 ; i++)
{
  sum2 += v2[i];
}
```

you perform 2 loops so more instructions, but you read contiguous memory in both cases: caches work in an optimal way (What takes most time in "modern" computers is more memory access/cache misses than executing code)

BTW I doubt that the compiler could group those 2 loops.

The second case takes less control instruction count, but the memory isn't read contiguously.

Also: optimizer use to "unroll" loops, thus reducing the negative effect of control instruction.

So what you gain on one side, you lose on the other side. Those optimizations need to be benched, and you could have greater variations depending on the processor architecture.

Comment: The cache utilization is good in both cases: when a cache line (for the vectors data) is loaded, the whole of it is used in the computation. The variant with one fused loop uses two cache lines, but neither of them causes the eviction of the other, so it's essentially the same.